# Can Grapher plot periodic functions, other than trigonometric ones?

Tags: macos, grapher, graph

That is, something like:

> f(x) = f(x+c)

Where `c` is an arbitrary constant. Examples:

[image]

How might I get grapher to chart this or select an appropriate tool to visualize these functions?

Comment: This is essentially a mathematical question. The answer isn't specific to Grapher.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't apply to Apple hardware or software.

Comment: This is totally on topic here. Using any software on covered hardware is explicitly allowed and encouraged. See [help] for details. Ask, an answer explaining how this is about math and not about grapher might be the correct answer to post here as an answer and not just a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, indeed it can:

- **Square wave:** try something like `y = (-1)^round(x)`(but with proper formatting). Something like `y = (round(x+0.5) - round(x)) - 0.5` would also work.
- **Sawtooth wave:** try something like `y = x mod 1` or, more elaborately, `y = 2((x-0.5) mod 1) - 1`. However, something like `y = x - round(x)` would also work. If you don't like any of these, try something like `y = x - floor(x)`.

The triangular wave is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Of course, you can also use the truncated Fourier series, but that may be too wiggly for your taste.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If anyone reads this comment, you can also find some really good stuff in the menu bar under `Examples`. There's one item for periodic functions.